# Use sum of multiple pandas columns in mapping a function

Tags: function, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a new column in my DataFrame.

I want the new column to be a*b if the sum of a few other columns is == 0, 1 if the sum is == 1, and 0 otherwise.

The number of columns that I am summing across is dynamic in that it may be 3 columns I am summing across or it could be 100.  I have a list of those column names (list_to_check) which could be of any length.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [2,3,4], 'c':['dd','ee','ff'], 'd1':[5,0,1], 'd2':[5,0,1], 'dn':[5,0,1]})

list_to_check = ['d1','d2','dn']

def func(a,b,c):
    if sum(c) == 0:
        a*b
    elif sum(c) == 1:
        1
    else:
        0

df['new_column'] = np.vectorize(func)(df.a,df.b,df[list_to_check])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vals = df[list_to_check].sum(1)
df['new_col'] = 0
df.loc[vals == 0, 'new_col'] = df.a * df.b
df.loc[vals == 1, 'new_col'] = 1
```

Comment: It would be good if you included an explanation with your answer instead of just code.

Comment: Perfect.  I didn't know about df.loc and this example actually filled in quite a few gaps that I was missing.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: good to hear @chris. yeah, there are definitely weird corners of indexing in pandas. (e.g. i've had to use `slice(None)` on more than one occasion)